# What is the collect set equivalent in BigQuery for Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have below table wherein I am trying to find an `array set` for a given `id`. I know `collect_set` is available in Hive, but I want to know its equivalent in BigQuery. I am using `Standard SQL`.

Here is my query

```
with temp as (
select "1" as id, "a" as source_field
union all
select "1" as id, "b" as source_field
union all 
select "1" as id, "b" as source_field
)
select id, string_agg(source_field) as op
from temp
group by id
```

This returns

```
id   op
1   a,b,b
```

whereas I need

```
id   op
1   a,b
```

because I only want distinct members for a given `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `string_agg(distinct source_field)` as in below example

```
select id, string_agg(distinct source_field) as op
from temp
group by id
```

Comment: thank you, that works. Just a followup question - will the `op` field be of type `array` ?

Comment: if you need op as an array - you can use `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT source_field) AS op`

Comment: will I able to perform a `group by operation` on that `array` in downstream queries then ?

Comment: Btw, but obviously you can group by string :o) the potential issue there is ordering. have in ming if you use DISTINCT in _AGG function - you cannot use ORDER BY - so `a,b` can in other cases be `b,a` and this will break you logic of grouping. As I said - if you will get into issue like this  - just post new question with all relevant details - so we will be able tohelp

Comment: yes you are correct, thanks Mikhail - I have accepted the answer.